# Postgresql 10 pl/pgsql test if column exits in a RECORD variable

Tags: plpgsql, record, exists

I have a function that starts like this

```
create or replace function dms_functions._enqueue_matter_property(ijob_id integer) 
returns json 
as $$
--
declare
  irow                                 record;
begin

    select * from 
    public.netdocuments_matter_extract 
    where property_id = ijob_id
    limit 1
    into irow;
```

-- Now process irow

public.netdocuments_matter_extract is a view that may differ depending on the properties in the DMS.

Is it possible to test irow to see if a column exists?
Something like

```
  if exists(irow.parent_property) then
     -- do something with the irow.parent_property
  end if;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible in clean plpgsql, because there are not any property for dynamic access to records (now, it can be changed in future). But you can convert record to builtin jsonb type, and then can do test of field existence:

```
do $$
declare
  r record; 
  colname text = 'relnamex';
begin
  select * from pg_class limit 1 into r;
  if to_jsonb(r) ? colname then
    raise notice 'record has column %', colname;
  else
    raise notice 'record has not column %', colname;
  end if;
end;
$$;
NOTICE:  record has not column relnamex
```